# Redirect javascript Form

Tags: javascript, php, chat, irc

I am trying to figure out how to make a form rediect for my website.

```
<form id="redirect_form" method="POST" action="http://mypage.net/index.php?autojoin=">
    <input type="TEXT" name="field_1" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET ['autojoin']); ?>">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('redirect_form').submit();
</script>
```

If I want to type in the box TheLobby, I want it to redirect to http://mypage.net/index.php?autojoin=TheLobby

I can't figure out why when I go to the page I have it just auto directs over to http://mypage.net/index.php?autojoin=

Comment: First thing JavaScript is not the same as Java so you should not use the Java tag. Secondly where is `$_GET['autojoin']` defined? Thirdly your JavaScript code currently redirects the user before they can input anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is submitting the form even before a user can enter any details.

Instead use this code:

```
<form id="redirect_form" method="POST" action="http://mypage.net/index.php?autojoin=">
    <input type="text" name="field_1" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET ['autojoin']); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```